# How do I make the left of my logo image unclickable?

Tags: html, css

[Ok here is my complete page](http://codepen.io/league95/pen/dGwLQM)
I'm trying to work on my portfolio page, and so far, I'm trying to make my logo image unclickable from its left margin, but I can't figure out how.

Here is my code so far:

HTML for logo:

```
    <!-- My img logo -->
    <a class ="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-logo" 
    src="http://i.imgur.com/H1mje3y.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

CSS for logo:

```
.img-logo{
height: 200%;
margin: -9px 0 30px 500px;
border-radius: 40%;
border: 3.5px solid maroon;
}
```

As you can see I had to set the margin for left to 500 to center my logo, but I don't want the margin to be clickable by hovering over it, I just want the logo to be clickable!! How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You really should just wrap it in a wrapper `div` and put `text-align: center` on that, then get rid of your margin on `.img-logo`  Something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class ="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img class="img-logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/H1mje3y.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>

    .wrapper {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .img-logo{
       display: inline-block;
       height: 200%;
       border-radius: 40%;
       border: 3.5px solid maroon;
    }
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/napoleon/pen/GoLoBJ)

Comment: I have to go out now but yours seems promising, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
.img-logo{
    margin: -9px 0 30px 500px;
    border-radius: 40%;
    border: 3.5px solid maroon;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Saved me there

Comment: It'll work, but it's a hack.  You don't have to use `position: absolute` in this case, so you shouldn't.  If it's positioned absolutely it takes it out of the normal flow of the DOM and will break on different screen sizes if you use pixels, unless you set the width of the page.  If you're going to position it absolutely you should use percentages, not px.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

Add the margin instead to `.navbar-brand`, if `.navbar-brand` is already used somewhere else add a new class or replace the class.

Comment: That makes my logo not centered anymore.

Comment: @NishaShlaymoon http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKRyGL Seems to work fine, just the css was getting overridden and is a mess to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pointer-events: none`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/)

http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/WrWryp?editors=0110

```
.img-logo{
height: 200%;
margin: -9px 0 30px 500px;
border-radius: 40%;
border: 3.5px solid maroon;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I can still hover over the margin and the mouse will still turn into a hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can always break up the image and "stitch" them together with CSS ingenuity, and wrap the desired part in a hyperlink element...

`<img src="" alt="" id="non-clickable"><a href=""><img src="" alt="" id="clickable" ></a>`

...but that creates more problems than solutions when it comes to responsive design. Avoid this method.

You will have to work with map and area elements for the best result.

The `<area>` element defines a region that can be associated with a hyperlink. This element must be nested in a `<map></map>` element. Both of these tags are supported by Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox, Safari, and Opera.

See the following example:

```
<img src="MyLogo" alt="My Logo" width="100" height="100" usemap="#logoMap">
```

Then apply the **map** element, associated through the **usemap** attribute.

```
<map name="logoMap">
 <area shape="rect" coords="x1, y1, x2, y2" href="link.html" alt="clickable">
 <area shape="rect" coords="x1, y1, x2, y2" alt="non-clikable">
</map>
```